# How to read csv with pandas in tmp directory in aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda to read some data from a csv into a dataframe, manipulate said data then convert it back to a csv and make an api call with the new csv all on a python lambda.

I am running into an issue using pandas.read_csv command.  It ends my lambdas trigger execution with no errors.

```py
os.chdir('/tmp')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/tmp', topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        if '.csv' in name:
            testdic[name] = root
            print(os.path.isfile('/tmp/' + name))
            print(os.path.isfile(name))
            df = pd.read_csv(name)
            df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/' + name)
```

Both os.path.isfile return true and i have tried both versions of read_csv, both do not work and end the lambda prematurely without error.

I have confirmed the csv is downloaded into the lambda tmp directory, I can read and print off rows of the csv in tmp. However when i run  = pd.read_csv('/tmp/file.csv') or changing my directory to /tmp and doing  = pd.read_csv('file.csv') it ends the lambda with no error and does not pass that point in the code.  I am using pandas 0.23.4 as that is what I need to use and the code works locally.  Any suggestions would be helpful

Expected results should be the csv being read into a dataframe so I can manipulate it.

*FIXED:  Could not just use '/tmp/' + filename.  Had to use os.path.join(root, filename), also had to increase the timeout of my lambda due to file size.*

Comment: Use `file_path = os.path.join(root, name)` and then `pd.read_csv(file_path)`?

Comment: Why is `chdir` needed. It can be done directly without it.

Comment: I used chdir based on other stack overflow advice.  The os.path.join allowed the smaller file to read in which showed me the issue was also my timeout was too short.  Thanks!

Comment: Did it work finally?

Comment: Yes increasing the lambda timeout and using the os.path.join got it working.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

os.path.join - works for different platforms

Use

```
file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
```

and then

```
pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

NOTE: Increase the AWS lambda timeout as suggested in comments by @Gabe Maurer